# Store Image NSData to varbinary SQl server using php

Tags: php, ios, sql, sql-server

I am using iPhone app which capture picture , I want to save this picture in sql server database using php. The formate for image store in sql server which I am using is VarBinary. I want to store my NSData of image in VarBinary so that Image can be saved in database.
Please see below the code which I am using to insert the image. Basically image is stored in image1 column with data type var

```
 <?php
           $Image1 = $_POST["Image1"];
           $Image2 = "0x";
           $Image3 = "0x";
           $Image4 = "0x";
           $Image5 = "0x";
           try
          { 
         $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO TableM (Image1, Image2, Image3, Image4, Image5)
         VALUES ($Image1, convert(VARBINARY(max), $Image2), convert(VARBINARY(max), $Image3), convert(VARBINARY(max), $Image4), convert(VARBINARY(max), $Image5))");
         $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
                 {
                  $response = new stdClass();
                                               $response->results = "Record added successfully";
                                               echo json_encode($response);                                               
                               }
                               else
                               {

                                               $response = new 
                                                          stdClass();
                                               $response->results = 
               "No record added";
                                               echo 
            json_encode($response);

                               }

                               $db = null;             
       }
       catch(Exception $e)
       {
       echo($e->getMessage());
        }


   }    catch (PDOException $e) {
   print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
               die();
   }

 ?>
```

Comment: Petty sure `VarBinary` can't hold more 8kb of data. Maybe you should put the images in a directory and save the path in your db

Comment: @WillParky93 I was storing the images in directory but client is asking to store in database and confirms that images can be stored more than 8Kb but I am not much sure

Comment: I don't get it man, whats wrong with using images in a directory? Sounds like terrible practice to store them in the database, I'd advise your client to not make this change

Comment: If you have to use the SQL, then I'd use [fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) to get the bytes and then use that in my query instead of letting SQL do it because that's where I think it's failing. Also, you are vulnerable to sql injection. Please use `bind_param` (or `bindParam` if using PDO)  if you're using prepared statements. You defeat the purpose of it without binding.

Comment: @WillParky93 I tried to save image more than 40Kb from asp.net and it works